# How can I add a popup on hover for a graphic using the ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

[I created this JSFiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/fh2wrd02/)

Currently, a user needs to click on the graphic point to see the attribute. How can I make it so the user only needs to hover over the graphic for the popup to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the graphics to a [graphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html), and listen for this layer's [mouse-over](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#event-mouse-over) event to detect when the hover starts. Listen for the [mouse-out](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#event-mouse-out) event to detect when the user's mouse has left the graphic (in which case you may want to close the infoWindow).

There's a sample [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_hoverinfowindow.html) which demonstrates this, albeit in a slightly more complicated manner.

Comment: Thanks, the graphicsLayer is exactly what I needed. I hate how ESRI wants everyone to use the AMD module, but so many of their samples are still using the legacy module.

Comment: we're chipping away at migrating them all to AMD, but there are a LOT of samples.  any one in particular you'd like to see upgraded?

Comment: @JohnGravois I know you you guys are. I was just venting. Thanks for asking that's nice of you.